# Wordpress directing to Posts page (edit.php) instead of saving post

Tags: redirect, woocommerce-offtopic

I have got a clean build (**WordPress 3.9.1** running Twenty Fourteen theme).

I've **installed WooCommerce** plugin and added one product.

The product is a variable product with 65 variations.

When I **link all variations** and save, there are no issues. But editing any information such as stock quantities or price etc and hitting Update will cause the problem below.

Once I **click Update**, I am redirected to edit.php (the Posts page) and the **changes were not saved**. There is no error and everything seems to be running just fine.

Upon removing variations one by one I realised that **once there's less than 50**, the post **updates perfectly**.

I've tried increasing memory in PHP.ini, .htaccess, wp-config.php and nothing.

Any ideas at all as I'm absolutely lost on this one.

Many thanks in advance.

Michael

**EDIT**: In actual fact, you don't have to even attempt to change the properties of the new product. Even just trying to change this as it is will cause this issue.

Comment: Try deactivating all plugins. If that works perfectly, then it's because of some plugin, which is off topic here: [help/on-topic]

Comment: The only plugin that's installed is the WooCommerce one. I've recreated this issue with a brand new install. I have a funny feeling it's to do with Wordpress set up though.

Comment: Try to save a post after deactivating woocommerce.

Comment: WooCommerce uses a 'Products' as a custom post type. If I deactivate it then I won't be able to edit the post...?

Comment: Try increasing `post_max_size` in your PHP ini

Comment: I thought it might be that too but, as I mentioned, I have increased this (to 64M) to no avail. I even tried it with 256M but nothing changed- so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Please enable [`WP_DEBUG` mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and add error messages that come up to your question. If redirect are involved you might want to log errors as well, since they can be obscured.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this actually?
I have set WP_DEBUG to true and turned on WP_DEBUG_LOG:

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

But there's no Debug.log. Am I missing a step? I even created a blank debug.log, placed it in wp-contents directory and went through the process but nothing was saved to it?

Thank for all the help so far.

Comment: How does your system status look? http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-menu-items/#section-5

Comment: hmm... Everything is green and good to go except one thing...
SOAP Client:  Your server does not have the SOAP Client class enabled - some gateway plugins which use SOAP may not work as expected.

Comment: that's fine. wouldn't worry about that much. With the debug, try setting WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY to true as well if it's not already. define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);

Comment: Sorry guys, this is where my developer hat lets me down. I can't find the log info anywhere on my server. It's a shared server and there's a 'logs' directory with plenty of .GZ files in there but none seeming to relating to this website build. Am I looking in the right place do you think? Does the log file update immediately?

Comment: log file should update at the time an error or warning occurs. Does your host have a panel or something for viewing the error logs? Also, not sure if this will help, but I've used this private debug log snippet in the past with decent results: https://gist.github.com/webaware/4969753

Comment: I'll take a look into that. If it helps, I am getting a message at the top when I navigate my way back in to the product again stating 'The backup of this post in your browser is different from the version below.  Restore the backup.' Is there any info we can pull from that?

Comment: The control panel lists error logs (thanks for pointing that out to me). There hasn't been any recent errors logged relating to this build. So annoying. Also, I just tried increasing PHP Max Input Vars to 3000 but it did nothing. Since I'm on a shared server, I can't restart it. Do you think I need to do this for any of our here changes to take effect?

Comment: Change the `max_input_vars` via `.htaccess`, additionally see: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/problems-with-large-amounts-of-data-not-saving-variations-rates-etc/

Comment: There's a range of htaccess files that I have access to. Do I edit the one in the root or in the domain directory?

Comment: I'd change it for that installation, so in the root of your WP installation. I gave an [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113781/22534) about the woocommerce variation limit some time ago, which might be helpful - or not. Besides I have made the experience that handling the variations in steps works better, like saving after every run or some changes instead of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer on this, I found that setting the max_allowed_packets to 32 helped as well as turning off mod security on the host side.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might still be looking for an answer on this 6 years later. I recently just had a similar issue and found the culprit to be the file limit of my hosting account had been exceeded. There was no error or anything from Wordpress I was just knocked back to the posts page. Clearing an old backup to free some space immediately resolved this issue for me.